# calling jsp page from servlet not using session variable

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Im trying to achive the requirement as below using netbeans, tomcat and servlet.

I'm submitting the form to the servlet "Servlet1" with userid. and in Servlet1, I am creating the statusmessage based on userid I got from form and  that needs to be displayed on "welcome.Jsp" page.

my servlet code :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String nextPage = "";
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String statusMessage = "";
        String emailId = request.getParameter("EmailId");
       
        try {

           int i = 1;
            if (i != -1) {
                if (i >= 1) {
                    statusMessage = "User Authentication Success";
                    

                } else {
                    statusMessage = "User Authentication failed";
                }
            } else {
                statusMessage = "ooooppppsssss";
            }

        } catch (Exception se) {
            out.println(se);
        }
        // out.print(statusMessage);
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

The problem is: I'm not redirected to the page where I want to display the message and instead url ends up on the same page and not redirected.  I know we can set it in session and it can be accessed from "welcome.jsp" by `response.sendredirect` but is there any way I can achieve this without using the session?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it as request attribute as

```
request.setAttribute("idName",userid);
```

and access it in JSP using JSTL as `${idName}`

What is the error you are getting??

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String nextPage = "";
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String statusMessage = "";
        String emailId = request.getParameter("EmailId");

        try {

           int i = 1;
            if (i != -1) {
                if (i >= 1) {
                    statusMessage = "User Authentication Success";


                } else {
                    statusMessage = "User Authentication failed";
                }
            } else {
                statusMessage = "ooooppppsssss";
            }

        } catch (Exception se) {
            out.println(se);
        }
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.jsp");
    out.println(statusMessage);
    rd.include(request, response);
}
```